# customizing page margins properly

Tags: margins

I am new to latex and facing difficulties to make customizations.

In my thesis document, requirement of my institution for the page margins is that:

There should be 4 cm space from left, 2.5 cm from top, 2,5 cm from right and 2.5 cm from bottom.

And the page number should be placed just in the middle of the space from bottom. That is, there should be 1.25 cm distance from bottom.

I use below commands in my .cls file but I am not sure if everything, especially page number places, handled correctly.

```
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{% top = 2.5cm, bottom = 2.5cm, left = 4cm, right = 2.5cm,}
```

Also for the beginning of each chapter:

Requirement is that there should be 6 cm from to "CHAPTER X" title.

After chapter title, there should be 36 pt. space and then title of the chapter like "INTRODUCTION".
After the title, there should be 36 pt. distance again and then starts the beginning of the subsection.

So it will be like:

6cm space from top
CHAPTER XXX
36pt space
INTRODUCTION
36pt space
subsection ...

Lastly,

I used below command in the last part of the tex file to create a blank CV page. The requirement again is to have 6 cm space from top, 36 pt space and then the content.

```
\clearpage \addtotoc{CURRICULUM VITAE} %%
\vspace*{3.5cm}
\begin{center}
\Large{\textbf{CURRICULUM VITAE}}
\end{center}
The author of this thesis ........
```

I wonder how to setup the margins for these kind of special pages created via \clearpage.

I would be really happy if you can guide me on making these customisations related with page margins.

P.S

I share some guidance in below pictures:

[image: page margin for conclusion part as an example]

[image: page margin for referencepart as an example]

[image: page margin for abstract page as an example]

These requirements say for example that

there should be 6 cm from top of the page to "KAYNAKÇA = REFERENCES" title or "CHAPTER 6 = BÖLÜM 6" title.

After chapter title (i.e. CHAPTER 6 = BÖLÜM 6), there should be 36 pt. space and then title of the chapter like "SONUÇ VE ÖERİLER = CONCLUSION AND FUTURE WORK".

After the title (i.e. "SONUÇ VE ÖERİLER = CONCLUSION AND FUTURE WORK") , there should be 36 pt. distance again and then starts the beginning of the text content.

But for the abstract page, requirement is that ABSTRACT title should be placed 2.5 cm from top.

Best wishes,

Comment: Could you be more specific. Add a insert a picture thus we will see what you want to achive.

Comment: Thanks for your remark. I have uploaded some guidance as image format. I hope this helps to clarify my need.

Comment: Please translate it.

Comment: done, hope this is ok now.